# Как задать alias для инициализации и дальнейшего присвоения путей?

Tags: postgresql, bash, консоль, терминал, alias

Необходимо создать одну команду, которая будет выполнять несколько команд в терминале (bash), в том числе инициализацию пользователя с паролем.
Список и порядок выполнения команд:

1. `su postgres` (здесь запрашивается пароль);
2. **ввод пароля**; *- здесь я так понимаю простой точкой с запятой не отделаешься.*
3. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin;` *- это вводиться от пользователя posgres*
4. `export PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql/data;`
5. `pg_ctl start -l logfile;`
6. `psql -c 'select now()';`
7. `psql`

Система Debian
Пример:

> pangaea@Caesar: ~$ startpsql;

-далее выполняется список всех указанных выше команд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте sudo, у него в настройках можно прописать, что выполнять такую то команду (включая и shell-скрипт) под пользователем таким то, не запрашивая пароль. И это единственно верный способ ибо позволяет нигде не писать пароль в открытом виде

Comment: Как мне использовать sudo?

Comment: google: "sudo команда без пароля"

Comment: При чем здесь выполнение списка команд alias и sudo без пароля? Мне важно не писать все 7 команд (указанные в вопросе) в терминале, важно найти способ оптимизировать это все до одного слова startpsql(например)

Comment: делаете текстовый файл, например в папке /usr/local/bin или любой другой папке которая доступна в путях, называете его `startpsql`. в него пишите `#!/bin/bash` первой строкой и `sudo -u postgres startpsql2` второй строкой. Создаете рядом файл `startpsql2` пишите в него первой строкой `#!/bin/bash` после которой все строки которые должны быть выполнены под postgres. На оба файла ставите права на выполнение `chmod a+x файл`. Настраиваете sudo что бы позволяло без пароля выполнять startpsql2 нужному пользователю

Comment: http://savepic.ru/13370062.htm      сделал все как написано, но startpsql не работает

Comment: что значит "не работает", что он сообщает

Comment: Если я просто пишу  startpsql - команда не найдена;  Если  ./startpsql.sh - postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Это логично. файла с именем "startpsql" у вас нет, вы создали файл и именем "startpsql.sh" linux в отличие от windows не отбрасывает расширения в именах команд, хотите что бы в имени команды не надо было писать в конце .sh так и не добавляйте его к имени файла